# How to start Kotlin in Ubuntu using snap

Tags: ubuntu, kotlin, kotlin-native

**i install kotlin through snap in ubuntu 18 but when i write kotlin on terminal i get this error like

```
bhaskar@bhaskar-ThinkPad-L430://usr/local/bin$ kotlin
Command 'kotlin' is available in '/snap/bin/kotlin'
The command could not be located because '/snap/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
kotlin: command not found**
```

when i see by path by  snap is included in $PATH:

```
 bhaskar@bhaskar-ThinkPad-L430://usr/local/bin$ $PATH
bash: /home/bhaskar/bin:/home/bhaskar/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin: /usr/local/bin:/home/bhaskar/snap/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games: No such file or directory
```

so help me, thanks for your support .

Comment: As the error message says, `/snap/bin` is not in your `PATH`. What is unclear?

Comment: but in my default path is included.

Comment: No, it is not .

Comment: then how to add my new path in path environment

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your path contains "/home/bhaskar/snap/bin", but the system is looking in the "/snap/bin" directory. (So it is searching from the root directory and not from you home directory "/home/bhaskar").

You can find several ways to edit your path over here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path